# Why doesn't `nx` rebuild if the targets were removed?

Tags: typescript, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I am using `nx` to manage a packaged based monorepo written in `typescript`. I use `npx nx build app` command to build the code and the output folder is `dist`. The first time I run this command it will generates the `dist` folder that includes all compiled code. However, after I delete the `dist` folder and run the build command again, it doesn't generate the `dist` folder. The command output is:

```
 Nx read the output from the cache instead of running the command for 1 out of 1 tasks.
```

I understand that `nx` cache the build artifacts. But I don't know why it doesn't regenerate the `dist` output folder. And I don't know where the compiled files are located.

Comment: This seems to be an "issued" topic in nx, I encounter the same along with some more people: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/8614